# UIButton (programmatically added) ignoring touches

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uistackview

I've got a view hierarchy with

- one stack view with vertical orientation and a bunch of `UIButtons` added programmatically plus
- a second stack view with horizontal orientation partially overlapping the first view
- both stack views having the view controllers root view as common super view

`UIButtons` added to the first view respond to touches just fine.

`UIButtons` added to the second view ignore touches.

Both series of buttons are added to the stack views using **the same method**, i.e. all having `userInteractionEnabled` enabled, targets set up properly, etc.

Any ideas why *only* the buttons in the second stack view ignore touches..?

The view hierarchy looks like expected in Xcode's view debugger, i.e. the horizontal view is on top of everything else so nothing could potentially *eat* my touch events..

The buttons in the horizontal view have identical tags and targets as some of the buttons in the vertical stack view (representing some kind of '*More*..' functionality for the vertical buttons).

Any touch debugging facilities I could enable for the view hierarchy..?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to test both stack views independently. Try the horizontal only and then vertical only. Aftet that check what happens in the rootViewController under touchesBegan method. This might give you some clue. After that I would check if the view gets loaded properly in the view subclass method (drawRect and init) of your HorizontalStackView and VerticalStackView.

Comment: Ah... turns out the root view of the view controller hosting both stack views wasn't wide enough to cover the horizontal stack view. Screwed up the framework's touch detection logic.

Comment: Nice1 :). You solved it step by step. Always works =).

Comment: Yeah, listing which view controller got the touches actually was key! Would be great to have something akin responder chain debugging facilities for touch handling - on macOS we've got nice internal debugging categories for the former..